# Tried installing Ubuntu on a PC with Windows 7. Ubuntu did not install properly and Windows 7 won't boot. Please help

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, windows-7

I have been using windows 7 for many years, but wanted to learn more about ubuntu.

So I used EaseUS partition manager to create a new partition on my hard drive. I then burned Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on to a CD, and booted Ubuntu from the CD. After trying out ubuntu for a bit, I decided to install it. Here is what I did:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxme9.jpg

(screenshots and descriptions of everything I did is given in the album above).

Ubuntu still works from "Live CD" so I was able to copy my important files into a USB drive. All windows 7 files seems to be in tact as well.

What can I do to get windows 7 working again? My knowledge of how operating systems, and hard drives work is limited. I just a beginner to Ubuntu as well (I was installing it to learn more about it). So, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 0):

For Windows repair unable to detect the operating system, I think marking partition sda2 (your 100mb system partition) as "Active", should do the trick. Detailed instructions on how to do that are available here: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/88872-startup-repair-menu-doesn-t-see-operating-system.html#post767041

I am not sure why your installation failed, but I think sda4 was somehow mounted or in a bad state. I would suggest deleting that partition altogether, and using the "Use free space" install method in the "Installation type" step.

Alternatively, delete the partition (using Windows Disk Management tool, for example), and then create it manually as ext4 with mount point "/" if you want to.

Comment: Hey, when I run the "LIST DISK" command I do not see the 100MB system partition. Here is a screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/wZiziHp.jpg